# Android Calendar Count Month

Tags: date

how can i get the first day at 00:00 o clock and last day also at 00:00 of the last month (currentMonth -1) as Date.
I have values in Sqlite with a unix timestamp, is there any simple way to filter values from a specific Month. For example the current Month is June and i want to count how many values have June as unix timestamp ( June 2014, June 2013...) without specifying any Year or day.

I get the current Timestamp like this

```
Long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);    
               String lastmonth =  dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), lastmonth, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

I found out how to get last Month but still don't know how to get specific month for every year.